# How to interrupt a code after delay

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, softwareserial

I have a functionality on my mega 2560 to connect with other devices. Sometimes, devices can't answer. I don't want to wait for a longwhile. So, how can I interrupt the chunk of program after the specific amount of time?

My code for receiving messages is:

```
while (!(UCSR1A & (1<<RXC1)));
```

so, `millis` can't solve my problem because I haven't ability to check for conditional loops like that

```
if(currentMillis - previousMillis > interval) {
```

Comment: It's often better to mention why you would want to do such a thing. I'm guessing that you want to receive your messages every once in a while. It might be better to handle serial events in interrupts (for fastest receiving). Or to handle it in a timer interrupt (better timing).

Comment: The question might be better titled "How to break out of a loop with a timeout", since interrupts and delay have completely different meanings that you are using here.

Answer (score 1):

OMG, I was stupid. I can just place millis in this `while` condition.

Comment: 'if(currentMillis - previousMillis > interval) break;' may work as well. -- If the logic could become more complicated, a separate break statement for the conditions might make the code clearer.